# Where are the CakePHP blog tutorial CSS files?

Tags: php, cakephp

Having completed the Cake 2.0 blog tutorial, I would like to change the background color - a very simple first task.

I'm unable to locate expected CSS file.

Comment: Try using Firebug or Chrome's developer tools. You can find out exactly what is affecting the colors

Comment: like jprofitt said, else inject JS (not recommended but if you just need quickfix)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the CSS files in the `app/webroot/css` folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't set your own CSS in your layout, the default one used is `app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css`, find the color in there.

First uncommented part should be what you need to change:

```
body {
    background: #003d4c;
```

Change that (and/or any other colors) to the desired color.